# Get a character after white space in string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a string like this: `@"The Happy Day"` and I want to save only the `"THD"` in another string. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to capture first-letters, or capitals?  Should "The hAppy Day" return "TAD", or "ThD", or "THD"?

Comment: Sorry, read the title closer after my question. What language?  You have an operating system and development environment named, but this could be Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: Hi Bro,I mean  Should "The hAppy Day"  return "ThD" and Objective-C language. Thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this...

```
NSString *string = @"The  Happy Day";

// Create array of words in string...
NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

// Create array to hold first letter of each word...
NSMutableArray *firstLetters = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[words count]];

// Iterate through words and add first letter of each word to firstLetters array...
for (NSString *word in words) {
    if ([word length] == 0) continue;
    [firstLetters addObject:[word substringToIndex:1]];
}

// Join the first letter error into a single string...
NSString *acronym = [firstLetters componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

It can be done much better using the functional types in Swift such as `map`, but there aren't any built-in methods like that in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks, It helpful for me

Comment: @DongNguyen It should work with that specific string, but I've modified my answer anyway so that it skips empty words—this might happen if there are two spaces in a row, or one at either end of the string, and in any case should fix the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"The Happy Day";

NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
[[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if(obj){
            [result appendString:[((NSString *)obj) substringToIndex:1]];
        }

 }];
```